# How do I get Location property to show up on the Device Dashboard in Azure IoT Central?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

Currently I have a device template in IoT Central with the following property:

```
        {
        "@id": "dtmi:iotDevicesAnywhere:MfrAIUTModelIAA5Level_3o3:Location;1",
        "@type": [
            "Property",
            "Location"
        ],
        "description": {
            "en": "Device Location"
        },
        "displayName": {
            "en": "Location"
        },
        "name": "Location",
        "schema": "geopoint",
        "writable": true
    }
```

I have published an event to IoT Hub and see the Property update in the Raw Data for the device:

```
  {
   "Location": {
        "reported": {
            "value": {
                "lat": "41.5770160991936",
                "lon": "-83.5955713465806",
                "alt": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "_eventtype": "Property",
    "_timestamp": "2022-08-29T11:49:08.577Z"
   }
```

I have setup the Device Dashboard location as:
[image]

However on the device dashboard it is:
[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to send the location data (longitude and latitude) from your device as numbers instead of wrapping them in strings?

```
{
      "lat": 41.5770160991936,
      "lon": -83.5955713465806,
      "alt": 0
}
```

Comment: Good catch, that's correct and it should be worked, more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-use-location-data#add-location-capabilities-to-a-device-template

Comment: That is true @thomasricci.  Well partially. :) I created another View for the device template called "Edit Location" and put the Location property on it.  On the Device Dashboard for the device I have a "Map Property" view on it.   The property shows up correctly when I remove the quotes on the "Edit Location" Device View but on the Device Dashboard it still doesnt show up.  Wierd.